# What is effective mass of electrons and holes at room temperature of Al${}_{0.52}$In${}_{0.48}$As?

Tags: mass, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, data

I'm searching for those values, but usually they are given at very low temperatures, usually 77K or 4K. I'm looking mostly for bulk values.

I was thinking of applying Vegard's law to AlAs and InAs... but I prefer more empirical data.

Comment: https://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/palankovski/node40.html might be a good starting place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have access to the Journal of Applied Physics, this work is a comprehensive resource of III-V material parameters, including a brief discussion of the available references:

I. Vurgaftman et al., J. Appl. Phys. 89(11), 5815 (2001)
[link to article](https://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1368156)

$In_{0.52}Al_{0.48}As$ is discussed on page 5840 with a recommended value around $0.07 m_0$.

Edit: I just realized that you specifically asked for the eff. mass at room temperature, while Vurgaftman's work seems to give the values for $0\,K$. Sorry, I missed that at first.

There is another work by D. Olego et al. Appl. Phys. Lett. 41(5), 476 (1982) [link to article](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.93537), which provides a value for $295\,K$ at the order of $0.075\,m_0$, obtained from an extrapolation by measurements on $In_{1-x-y}Ga_{x}Al_{y}As$ with experimental data up to $y=0.27$ or so.